# Why does C++ have a ";" after a class declaration

Tags: c++

I'm starting to learn C++ and just out of curiosity, why does C++ require you to put a ";" at the end of the class declaration
for example:

```
class A
{
   /*...*/
};
```

In languages like java, it's used to signify an end of a statement.

What is different about

```
int i(5);
```

and the class above with regards to the semi-colon in C++? Does the compiler treat the class as a statement or does it have a different interpretation for it?

Comment: This question is very close to a "Why is C++ not like Java?" or "What are the differences between C++ and Java?".  Both of which are outside the scope of SO.

Comment: Why the heck is this getting upvotes....

Comment: @H2CO3, because *everybody* who programs C++ has been bitten by forgetting this little syntactic oddity. When you understand the reason for something you're less likely to forget it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Invalid argument. "I don't know the language" is a reason for learning the language, not for upvoting irrelevant off-topic crap.

Comment: @H2CO3, isn't the whole point of StackOverflow for learning? I fail to see why this would be off-topic.

Comment: @MarkRansom Of course the point is learning! But that does not happen by complaining why language X is not language Y. If OP doesn't like semi-colons, he should be perhaps programming in Python or VB instead of soliciting a rant. That's basically just noise.

Comment: @H2CO3 How am I soliciting a rant? All I wanted to know was the reason behind the ";" at the end of a class. Not complaining about C++'s way of doing things.

Answer (score 27):

because you can also define variables in the declaration:

```
class A {
        ...
} x, y, z;
```

Ending class declarations in a semicolon is basically saying explicitly that we are *not* declaring any variables of this type.

Comment: But what about when you don't?

Comment: @0x499602D2: how do you want to compiler to guess that the thing after the `}` isn't a variable if there's no terminator?

Comment: @0x499602D2: An empty terminated list needs its terminator just as much as a long terminated list.